# jooq select from multiple tables with mapInto

Tags: java, jooq

how can I fetch from 2 tables to map?

```
Map<Table1Record, LocalDate> map = dslContext.select(table1, table2.DATE)
            .from(table1).join(table2).on(table1.ID.eq(table2.ID))
            .fetchMap(table1, table2.DATE)
```

I tried to do like this, but it doesnt work. How can I select record?
`dslContext.select(table1.fields(), table2.DATE)` is ok. But it returns fields array, not record. I have only records without pojos

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to write this?

```java
Map<Table1Record, LocalDate> map = dslContext
    .select(table1.fields())
    .select(table2.DATE)
    .from(table1)
    .join(table2).on(table1.ID.eq(table2.ID))
    .fetchMap(table1, table2.DATE)
```